# ¿De que forma puedo obtener la diferencia en minutos de dos timepicker? en Java

Tags: java, android

Por favor podrían decirme como puedo capturar la hora que me arroja una `timepickerdialog` y guardarla como un numero `float` para restarla con otro `timerpickerdialog`, he tratado de convertir ese formato de hora y no he podido, no se la forma como se hace. Cuando corro la app puedo poner la hora inicial y final que se muestran en EditText pero al hacer el calculo se cierra la app. Gracias.

public void horainicial(View view) {

```
HoraInicial = Calendar.getInstance();
hora = HoraInicial.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
minutos = HoraInicial.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        thorainicial.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
       }

}
        , hora, minutos, false);
timePickerDialog.show();
```

}
    public void horafinal (View view){

```
    HoraFinal = Calendar.getInstance();
    hora = HoraFinal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minutos = HoraFinal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            thorafinal.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);


        }
    }
            , hora, minutos, false);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Cuál es el método que utilizas para calcular la diferencia de horas que hace que se cierre tu app podrías colocar el código

Comment: Lo he borrado, he intentado muchas veces, pero lo que he hecho es tratar de guardar el objeto tipo Calendar en un Date y después a un long con getTime... Averigue y me dijeron que ese método me devolvía la hora en milisegundos...Llevo estás variables a un método public void calcular (view view) para asignarselo a un botón y me muestre el resultado en un texview...pero me cierra la app apenas presiono el botón

Comment: Puedes obtener los valores en formato Date y a partir de eso puedes obtener la diferencia @Mauricio , agregue una respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Crea una valriable a nivel de clase para almacenar la hora inicial y final en formato `Date`

```
private Date horaInicial, horaFinal;
```

Ahora en cada TimePickerDialog obtiene los valores de hora inicial:

```
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        thorainicial.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);

        //*Obtiene valor de hora Inicial.
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        horaInicial = simpleDateFormat.parse(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);

       }

}
        , hora, minutos, false);
```

y hora final:

```
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        thorafinal.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);

    //*Obtiene valor de hora Inicial.
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    horaFinal = simpleDateFormat.parse(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);

    }
}
        , hora, minutos, false);
```

a partir de obtener estos valores puedes hacer uso del siguiente método el cual obtiene la diferencia entre ambos valores en formato `String`:

```
public String obtieneDiferencia(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    //Diferencia en millisegundos
    long different = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

    long secondsInMilli = 1000;
    long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
    long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
    long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

    different = different % daysInMilli;

    long elapsedHours = different / hoursInMilli;
    different = different % hoursInMilli;

    long elapsedMinutes = different / minutesInMilli;
    different = different % minutesInMilli;

    long elapsedSeconds = different / secondsInMilli;

    return "horas: " + elapsedHours + " minutos: " + elapsedMinutes + "segundos: " + elapsedSeconds;
}
```

Teniendo los valores de hora inicial y final puedes obtener el valor de la diferencia:

```
String diferencia = obtieneDiferencia(horaInicial, horaFinal);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es un gran avance...aún se cierra mi app al presionar el botón pero creo que ya es algo de error en sintaxis...pero ya me queda una idea más clara con su explicación.

Comment: Recuerda es importante revisar el LogCat cuando se cierra la app, que error se muestra? busca donde diga "Caused by". @Mauricio

Answer (score -1):

Mauricio, quizas podrias trabajarlo de esta manera e implementar tu lógica aquí:

```
int minutosUno = timePicker1.getCurrentMinute();
int minutosDos = timePicker2.getCurrentMinute();
```

espero sea de ayuda

Comment: Voy a intentarlo, gracias. pero si los timepickerdialog utilizan la hora del sistema, será que me genera error por ese lado también

Comment: de igual manera tendras "horas/minutos" y puedes realizar tus comprobaciones

Comment: Amigo mira que no me aparece el método getCurrentMinute...aparece en rojo