# Calcular el tiempo transcurrido entre dos horas en Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Al presionar un botón guardo la hora actual. Necesito que, al cerrar la app y al volverla a abrir, se calcule el tiempo transcurrido en minutos y segundos. Por ejemplo:

Sin contar la hora;

presiono el botón a las 7:**59:12**, seguido cierro la app y la vuelvo a abrir a las 8:**02:00**. Tendría que obtener un tiempo transcurrido de **1 minuto con 48 segundos.**

Encontré este fragmento de código, calcula los minutos, solo faltarían los segundos...

```
private void calculate(String hora1, String hora2) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date startDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(hora1);
        Date endDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(hora2);
        long difference = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
        if (difference < 0) {
            Date dateMax = simpleDateFormat.parse("24:00");
            Date dateMin = simpleDateFormat.parse("00:00");
            difference = (dateMax.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) + (endDate.getTime() - dateMin.getTime());
        }
        int days = (int) (difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        int hours = (int) ((difference - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * days)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        int min = (int) (difference - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * days) - (1000 * 60 * 60 * hours)) / (1000 * 60);
        Log.i("log_tag","Hours: " + hours + ", Mins: " + min);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Agradezco un montón su ayuda.

Comment: Coloca el codigo que hayas intentado para que puedan ayudarte mejor.

Comment: @RamiroBarone Ya puse el código que utilizo

Comment: hora1 y hora2 la traes de la base de datos? Están en formato Date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes como formato `HH:mm` y si quieres extraer también los segundos debes poner como formato `HH:mm:ss`.

No hagas tantas multiplicaciones de constantes, es mejor que pongas el valor ya calculado como una constante porque las multiplicaciones son caras para el procesador y en este caso te las puedes ahorrar.

Modificando un poco tu método `calculte` yo haría algo así:

```
private final int SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY = 86_400;
private final int SECONDS_IN_ONE_HOUR = 3_600;
private final int SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE = 60;

private void calculate(String hora1, String hora2) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date startDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(hora1);
        Date endDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(hora2);

        long start = startDate.getTime() / 1000;
        long end = endDate.getTime() / 1000;

        if(end < start)
            end += SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY;

        int difference = (int) (end - start);

        int days = difference / SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY;
        difference %= SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY;
        int hours = difference / SECONDS_IN_ONE_HOUR;
        difference %= SECONDS_IN_ONE_HOUR;
        int minutes = difference / SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE;
        difference %= SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE;

        System.out.println("Days: " + days + ", Hours: " + hours + ", Mins: " + minutes + ", Seconds: " + difference);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso del mètodo especificado en esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/352136/95) el cual realiza el calculo en base a los valores de tipo Date especificados como hora fecha inicial y fecha final.

#### Calcular el tiempo transcurrido entre dos horas.

```
public String obtieneDiferencia(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    //Diferencia en millisegundos.
    long different = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

    long secondsInMilli = 1000;
    long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
    long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
    long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

    different = different % daysInMilli;

    long elapsedHours = different / hoursInMilli;
    different = different % hoursInMilli;

    long elapsedMinutes = different / minutesInMilli;
    different = different % minutesInMilli;

    long elapsedSeconds = different / secondsInMilli;

    return "horas: " + elapsedHours + " minutos: " + elapsedMinutes /*+ "segundos: " + elapsedSeconds*/;
}
```

En tu caso ya tienes los valores como tipo Date, por lo tanto solo llama el mètodo de esta forma:

```
 Date startDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(hora1);
 Date endDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(hora2);

 String diferencia = obtieneDiferencia(startDate, endDate);

 Log.i("log_tag", diferencia);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay una clase llamada "Duration" que tiene un método llamado "between()" que nos permite sacar la diferencia entre dos fechas. Puedes leer más sobre esta clase en: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html

En tu caso lo primero que tenemos que hacer es un parse al formato que queremos y de inicio hay que declararlo con los componentes que queremos ("HH:mm:ss"). Aquí es donde tuviste tu primer error ya que tú declaraste un formato de "HH:mm" faltándote los segundos.

Luego utilizamos la clase **Duration** y su método **between()** para extraer la diferencia. En mi ejemplo yo puse que quería traer los segundos puesto que son los valores más pequeños que quieres buscar en cuestión tiempo. De ahí hacemos las operaciones correspondientes para transformarlos a minutos y a horas. Luego los guardamos en un array y por último imprimimos los valores.

El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String hora1 = "7:59:12";
    String hora2 = "8:02:00";

    try {

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date startDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(hora1);
        Date endDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(hora2);

        //method to get time between values
        Duration dur = Duration.between(startDate.toInstant(), endDate.toInstant());

        //variable to get the difference of time in seconds
        int value = (int) dur.getSeconds();

        //begins the magic
        int hours = value / 3600;
        int remainder = (int) value - hours * 3600;
        int mins = remainder / 60;
        remainder = remainder - mins * 60;
        int secs = remainder;

        //array to save the values
        int[] time = {hours , mins , secs};

        //print the values
        System.out.println("Hours: " + time[0] + ", Minutes: " + time[1] + ", Seconds: " + time[2]);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Como nota adicional quiero mencionar que tu diferencia de tiempo no es **1 minuto con 48 segundos** como tú lo mencionas, sino de **2 minutos con 48 segundos**.

Espero que mi respuesta te sea de ayuda.
Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, muy buena tu respuesta. Sin embargo, en algunas versiones de la API en Android la función de la clase Duration, en este caso, dentro de la función between(), al usar el toInstant(), no funciona; por esto no puedo usar este método.